# How can i get the total "Price" of the attributes "Price"?

Tags: jquery

I want to get the `cart` in the JS part to get a total summary of the price.

```js
$("#ui_pay").hide()
var cart = []
$(".addToCart").click(function(e) {
  cart.push($(this).attr("value"));
  $(this).html("<i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i> " + "Lade till ".concat($(this).val()))
  console.log(cart);
})
$(".continue").click(function(e) {
  if (cart === undefined || cart.length == 0) {
    $(this).html('<i class="fas fa-times"></i> ' + "Du måste lägga till något i korgen")
    $(this).css({
      "width": "200px"
    })
  } else {
    $("#ui").fadeOut()
    $('#ui_pay').fadeIn()
    $(".pricePay").html(cart)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="color: white;">Melee</span>
<a href="#bat" rel="modal:open"><img price="1000" value=" Basebollträ" class="melee" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/gtawiki/images/5/59/BaseballBat-GTAV.png/revision/latest?cb=20160612221707" alt=""></a>
<button price="1000" value="Basebollträ" class="addToCart"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
<a href="#apPistol" rel="modal:open"><img price="25000" value="" class="melee switchblade" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/gtawiki/images/f/fc/Switchblade-GTAV.png/revision/latest?cb=20161021210105" alt=""></a>
<button price="15000" value="Switchblade" class="addToCart"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
```

Comment: When you add to your `cart` array, add all the relevant information: `cart.push({value: $(this).attr("value"), price: $(this).attr("price")});` then you can add them up without having to refer back as in (inside a loop for cart array) `$("[value=" + this+ "]").attr("price")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the price into `cart`, not just the item name. I've changed it to an array of objects with both.

You should't make up attributes of your own like `price`. Use `data-price` instead.

Then you need a loop that adds up all the prices in the cart.

```js
$("#ui_pay").hide()
var cart = []
$(".addToCart").click(function(e) {
  cart.push({item: $(this).val(), price: $(this).data("price")});
  $(this).html("<i class='fas fa-shopping-cart'></i> " + "Lade till ".concat($(this).val()))
  console.log(cart);
})
$(".continue").click(function(e) {
  if (cart === undefined || cart.length == 0) {
    $(this).html('<i class="fas fa-times"></i> ' + "Du måste lägga till något i korgen")
    $(this).css({
      "width": "200px"
    })
  } else {
    $("#ui").fadeOut()
    $('#ui_pay').fadeIn()
    var total_price = 0;
    cart.forEach(({price}) => total_price += price);
    $(".pricePay").html(total_price)
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span style="color: white;">Melee</span>
<a href="#bat" rel="modal:open"><img price="1000" value=" Basebollträ" class="melee" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/gtawiki/images/5/59/BaseballBat-GTAV.png/revision/latest?cb=20160612221707" alt=""></a>
<button data-price="1000" value="Basebollträ" class="addToCart"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
<a href="#apPistol" rel="modal:open"><img price="25000" value="" class="melee switchblade" src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/gtawiki/images/f/fc/Switchblade-GTAV.png/revision/latest?cb=20161021210105" alt=""></a>
<button data-price="15000" value="Switchblade" class="addToCart"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
<br>
<button class="continue">Show total</button>
<div id="ui_pay">
Total price: <span class="pricePay"></span>
</div>
```